# How do I ensure that the user can see the whole list?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a list in row 2 of 3 in a grid. The grid is defined as following:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My ListBox:

```
<ListBox Foreground="Black" x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Placement}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Width="45" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Username}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Width="160"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Score}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Width="160" TextAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the first row I have the title, and in the last I have a ad (taking 100px). Listbox gets populated in a WebClient DownloadComplete.

Currently my list holds 10 items, but I can only slide down to number 5,4 (I see the top of row 6).

Height is not defined in my listbox

Comment: can you provide a sample of you ListBox xaml?

Comment: Have you enabled a Vertical Scrollbar?

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot Added the ListBox code. it gets populated in a WebClient DownloadComplete

Comment: It doesn't look like your ListBox is being placed into the second row of the second grid (Grid.Row="1"). Is the listbox a direct child of the grid or is it in another control? also is the grid in a scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set height of listbox. then it can scroll to every item

Comment: I've tried to set it something high like 800, and with a StackPanel with the height of 78 it should be enough. I'll have to play around with it

Comment: You should not the height of the listbox. It is designed to fill the space given to it. If directly in the grid, that's a lot, if it's within a StackPanel then it will be a small amount of space given to it